# How to fill out the userform by the product name you typed

Tags: vba, excel

I hope I explain clearly

I have a form that I type in the entries and insert into a sheet, and it works well

Now I need that when I type a product, the rest of the boxes will get their values from the table, if they exist

That is, if the product already exists, will fill the appropriate values

Then I change as needed, and click the Update button, and update the same line

So I need 2 things

1. If the product already exists, fill in the appropriate values in the rest of the boxes on the form
2. Update the same line of product

[image: My form]

That's the code I have

```
    Private Sub update_Click()
    'When you click the Add button
    'Populates the data in the sheet
    '~~~~>>>>>> I do not know how to put on the same line of the selected product
        Dim lRow As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets("sheet")
        lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        With ws
            'Me.ComboBox3.Value >>>> Here he should look up the row with the same cell value and write down the following values
            .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
        End With
    End Sub
    Private Sub add_Click()
'Not related to here
    End Sub
```

I would be happy to get help / concepts / direction from the experts here

Note: There is a unique line for each product

If this is not clear, please write to me

Comment: What column has Product ID? What column has value for `A` text box? `B`?

Comment: The product in column A and the values in the b-c columns

Comment: I can change later as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to auto populate your other 2 fields if matched product ID is found. Every time the `ComboBox1` is changed, it will look for the Product ID using `Range.Find` method. If the product is found, it will then import the corresponding value from `Column B` and `Column C` by using `Offset(r, c)`

You will need to ammend the options of `Range.Find` method to meet your needs. There are a lot of options, so it is best you see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) link and add them as you see fit. Sounds like you will want `Lookin:= xlWhole` for starters.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet")
Dim Found As Range

Set Found = ws.Range("A:A").Find(ComboBox1.Value)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    Me.TextBox1 = Found.Offset(, 1)
    Me.TextBox2 = Found.Offset(, 2)
Else                                            'Revert back to blank if nothing is found
    Me.TextBox1 = ""
    Me.TextBox2 = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Now it works, thank you very much, I will explore the possibilities of `.Find`, is it also suitable for my second question? Or need something more suitable ?

Comment: Same method is suitable

Comment: One problem, the values remain if the product does not exist, ie there is a product "AB" and I continue "ABC", the values of "AB" remain if "ABC" does not exist

Comment: alkjfd;lajf;adskf try again :)

Comment: This is still not true :(, the values remain if the product exists, ie there is a product "ABC" and I write "AB", and the row of "ABC" is before "AB", the values of "ABC"

Comment: I left a comment earlier that got removed. You need to amend the `Range.Find` options to look at the whole cell. You need to set to `Lookin:= xlWhole` and add any other options that a relevant

Comment: I added a link to my question. You should have everything you need <3

Answer (score 0):

For those who need, I've written the full code here, and it works well

Thanks to @urdearboy

```
    Option Explicit
```

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets1")
    Dim Found As Range
    Set Found = ws.Range("A1:C3").Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        Me.TextBox1 = Found.Offset(, 1)
        Me.TextBox2 = Found.Offset(, 2)
                Else
        Me.TextBox1 = ""
        Me.TextBox2 = ""
    End If
    End Sub
```

```
    Private Sub update_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets1")
    Dim Found As Range
    Set Found = ws.Range("A1:C3").Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            Found.Offset(, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
            Found.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
    End If
    End Sub
```

```
    Private Sub add_Click()
        Dim lRow As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheets1")
        lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        With ws
            .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
        End With
    End Sub
```