# How to fill out the userform by the product name you typed If there are two identical products in excel

Tags: excel, vba

This question is a continuation of a [previous question that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692372/how-to-fill-out-the-userform-by-the-product-name-you-typed) was successfully solved thanks to the experts here

> I have a form that I type in the entries and insert into a sheet, and
>   it works well
>
> Now I need that when I type a product, the rest of the boxes will get
>   their values from the table, if they exist
>
> That is, if the product already exists, will fill the appropriate
>   values, in the rest of the boxes on the form

But I see that the situation may be listed **two identical products**, and it is **not** a mistake

How do I do that according to the choice in "ComboBox1"

Fill in the rest of the form with the appropriate values

That is, it will recognize the location of the selection in a drop-down list

If it was a first line selection, it would fill the values by the first line
And so on

And when I change the values, it changes to the same line

Is it possible to do such a thing? **Or is it better to think of another idea?**

Hope this is understandable

[image: example]

The code I've used so far

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets")
Dim Found As Range
Set Found = ws.Range("A1:C3").Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, MatchCase:=False)
If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    Me.TextBox1 = Found.Offset(, 1)
    Me.TextBox2 = Found.Offset(, 2)
            Else
    Me.TextBox1 = ""
    Me.TextBox2 = ""
End If

End Sub
Private Sub update_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets")
Dim Found As Range
Set Found = ws.Range("A1:C3").Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, MatchCase:=False)
If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        Found.Offset(, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
        Found.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's certainly possible, you can reference to the index of the element in your combobox, but are you sure this is the *proper* solution? Are you sure your users will understand what you mean? Can you not think of any other way around?

Comment: According to the values filled in the rest of the boxes you can see what he meant, but I see that this may lead to mistakes, so better to avoid it, right